# Setup project creating database

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-project

I am not sure but i think i have problems with some permissions...

I have this method:

```
  static void ExecuteCommand(string _Command)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + _Command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        //procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
```

First, i was executing this code in a desktop app and it works.

```
  string createDB = @"sqlcmd -S " + SQLINSTANCE + @" -Q ""CREATE DATABASE " + DBNAME + @"""";
  ExecuteCommand(createDB);
```

But now im trying to execute it in the setup-project with custom action getting this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

If i execute this string in a cmd console (with and without admin privileges) it work perfectly...

Where is the problem?

Comment: How do you connect to the database server? With integrated security (using the Windows login) or with SQL server authentication?

Comment: Try to open your visual studio in administrative mode

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar it is a setup .msi.. im not executing this with visual studio

Comment: @stickybit i am not connecting to a database, i am creating it only with this string. Edit: Sorry, i read wrong, but that is it, this string, without indicating security

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar ok, i tryied with Visual Studio in Admin mode and it works. But i need that works from setup.msi directly, without Visual Studio

Comment: Try to run .msi file as an administrator.

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar This option not appear by right clicking on msi file

Comment: This is permission related issue, please google it and try to find solution. I can't help you without looking into what exactly you are trying and what you want to achieve

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar I did it and I can not find anything, that's why I'm asking here. It's simple, I want to create a database during the installation process with a custom action, but I get this error, I do not know why, because exactly the same code outside the installer works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the properties [UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `runas`.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.Domain = "domain";
psi.UserName = "username";
psi.Password = password;
```

Comment: I cant do it because the user is variable, i dont know who is

Comment: Possible to get as parameters then? It will work in this way.